# Exposing an internal class as a public property

Tags: .net, encapsulation, public, class-library, internal

In a class library I am working on, I had a class with lots of properties so I refactored it to be composed of a few smaller, *internal* classes. However, now I have marked these classes as *internal*, the code won't compile when I expose them as public properties on the original class. For example:

```
public class TheOriginalClass
{
    public MyInternalClass InternalClassProperty { get; set; }
}

// It doesn't make sense to use this by itself
internal class MyInternalClass
{
    public string InterestingProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Ideally, I would like to encapsulate these *helper* classes within the assembly as it doesn't make sense for them to be instantiated anywhere else.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're exposing the content of the class to the outer world, mark it as `public` so you'll later know that the class is a publicly visible one so you'll be reluctant to change the public interface so often. There is not point in marking it `internal` if that's not going to be internal like that.

If you really want that, use reflection with the calling assembly and with the binding flag `BindingFlags.NonPublic` while retrieving the classes (and their constructors) in the assembly.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't make sense to have a `internal` class as the static type of a `public` property. The consumer of that property in another assembly wouldn't be able to do anything useful with it.

Perhaps you wanted to have a `public` helper class with an `internal` constructor to prevent others from creating it.

Or make the type of the property a public interface, and implement that interface in an internal class.

Answer (score 2):

If the internal class implements a public interface, you can simply expose that instance as the interface type.